# HTTP POST call from Android

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

I'm trying to send data to an PHP webservice trough POST from an Android app... It always returns:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.joaocarreira.familylocator, PID: 1059
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Here is my android code:

```
    String newLat = Float.toString(lat);
    String newLng = Float.toString(lng);
    String newSos = Boolean.toString(sos);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost monitorRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost/monitor.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentDateTime", currentDateTime));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", newLat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", newLng));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sos", newSos));

    try {
        monitorRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(monitorRequest);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    nameValuePairs.clear();
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$currentDateTime = $_POST["currentDateTime"];
$lat = $_POST["lat"];
$lng = $_POST["lng"];
$sos = $_POST["sos"];

$dbconection = new DBConnect();
$query = "INSERT INTO locationhistory (date, lat, lng, sos) VALUES ('$currentDateTime', '$lat', '$lng', '$sos')";
$dbconection->putData($query);

echo "OK";
?>
```

Comment: this is purely an android error and has nothing to do with php. did you even READ the error message?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. In Android applications, one may not execute network code on the Main thread. This means you have to create a separate thread for your code. This can by done via an implementation of the `AsyncTask`class. Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)